# inconsistency sample time matlab simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, sample-rate

I need to do some research, which requires multiplying the recorded sample of the wav signal by the harmonic sine and cosine function. At the initial launch, I could listen to the recorded VAV file, but the 1 kHz harmonic oscillation was angular, as if there were not enough samples. Then I went into the settings and changed the "Solver selection" to "Fixed-step" and set the fixed step "1e-6". Now the sine wave has become smooth, but it works as long as the signal block vav is off, as soon as I start using them together, an error occurs as in the photo.

Is it possible to somehow get rid of this discrepancy?

I don't really know how to set these values correctly. Why there are several of them:

1. Samples per audio channel (for multimedia file)
2. Samples per period (for sin)
3. Sample time (fo sin)
4. Fixed-step size (fundamental sample time) in model settings.

I need to open an audio file with a sampling rate of 4100 Hz. How to set everything else correctly, I don't understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llYjc.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked that now all signal sources (your file and the sine, cosine blocks) use the same fixed step size?

Comment: I explained the problem in more detail above. Please guide me, please give me a hint. I posted a photo with block settings